# Why does resolving dependencies using Ivy not work in Android's "-pre-build" Ant target?

Tags: android, ant, ivy

As Android Java projects use Ant as a build tool, using Ivy for dependency management seems like a natural choice to me. However, while the basic setup works fine, I'm running into a strange issue. I've created a [fork of an existing example on GitHub](https://github.com/sschuberth/IvyAndroidExample) to easily reproduce the problem.

The point is, dependencies get downloaded into the "libs" directory just fine, but the build process as invoked by `ant debug` does not seem to find the JARs. **However**, it works fine if I call the "resolve" target not as part of my overloaded "-pre-build" target, but manually like in `ant resolve debug`.

I have verified that the libraries are really in "libs" just before "-pre-build" finishes (by listing the files in "libs" as part of the "-pre-build" target), so I'm really wondering why they cannot be found.

To reproduce, it's important to delete the libraries from "libs" before running ant. Any ideas what's going wrong here?

```
resolve:
[ivy:retrieve] :: Apache Ivy 2.3.0-rc1 - 20120416000235 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:retrieve] :: loading settings :: file = /Users/seschube/development/IvyAndroidExample/ivysettings.xml
[ivy:retrieve] :: resolving dependencies :: com.example#ivy-android-example;0.1
[ivy:retrieve]  confs: [default]
[ivy:retrieve]  found org.acra#acra;4.2.3 in acra
[ivy:retrieve]  found com.google.inject#guice;2.0-no_aop in maven2
[ivy:retrieve]  found com.google.zxing.core#core;1.6 in zxing
[ivy:retrieve] :: resolution report :: resolve 115ms :: artifacts dl 5ms
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   3   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   4   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[ivy:retrieve] :: retrieving :: com.example#ivy-android-example
[ivy:retrieve]  confs: [default]
[ivy:retrieve]  4 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (1195kB/76ms)

-pre-build:
     [echo] The "libs" directory contains: acra-4.2.3.jar;core-1.6.jar;guice-2.0-no_aop-javadoc.jar;guice-2.0-no_aop.jar

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to /Users/seschube/development/IvyAndroidExample/bin/classes
    [javac] /Users/seschube/development/IvyAndroidExample/src/com/example/IvyAndroidExampleActivity.java:7: error: package org.acra does not exist
    [javac] import org.acra.*;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] /Users/seschube/development/IvyAndroidExample/src/com/example/IvyAndroidExampleActivity.java:8: error: package com.google.inject does not exist
    [javac] import com.google.inject.*;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] /Users/seschube/development/IvyAndroidExample/src/com/example/IvyAndroidExampleActivity.java:9: error: package com.google.zxing does not exist
    [javac] import com.google.zxing.*;
    [javac] ^
    [javac] 3 errors

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Is ivy built into the Android build system? I downloaded the github project but was unable to see the logic of your "-pre-build" target (because it's contained in a build file you import from the Android SDK distribution). I'm guessing the issue is that you need to "bootstrap" your build by getting ivy to download your dependencies, then the standard build logic could find the jars in the normal "lib" directory.

Comment: No, Ivy is not part of the Android build system. I forgot to say that you already need to have Ivy installed (e.g. in ~/.ant/lib), or add a bootstrap target to the Ant file. In any case, as you can see from the log, Ivy is installed and actually copies the artifacts correctly from its local cache to the project's libs directory. The Android SDK just defines "-pre-build" as an empty target which is meant to be overridden, which is what I'm doing in the build.xml file. You just need to uncomment it.

Comment: I think Mark was talking about this file import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" /> and i would be talking about the <loadproperties srcFile="local.properties" />
<property file="ant.properties" />. I'm sorry I still wasn't able to run your project.

Comment: I've added an Ant target to "bootstrap" Ivy now, hopefully that finally allows you guys to start building the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found out what's going on: The Android SDK's build.xml adds all JARs from the `libs` directory to the `project.all.jars.path` property as part of the `-build-setup` target. But this is too early if Ivy's `retrieve` target is called as part of `-pre-build`, because `-build-setup` is called before `-pre-build`. So `-pre-build`, although meant to be overridden, is the wrong place. As there seems to be no other "dummy" target meant to be overridden before `-build-setup` is called, I'm now overriding `-build-setup` in my build.xml file with a version that depends on `retrieve` and the original `-build-setup` like this:

`<target name="-build-setup" depends="retrieve,android_rules.-build-setup" />`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without looking at the build.xml itself.

However, when you use `<ivy:resolve>` to do your resolution, it doesn't automatically put the libraries in your project. Most likely, they're in `$HOME/.ivy2/cache`. What you need to do is before you use your `<javac>` task is to run `<ivy:cachepath>` to create a path reference you can use in your compile:

You can see I've created the required classpath called `main.classpath` with my `<ivy:cachepath>` task. I can then use this to include it in my `<javac>` task.

If you want to actually download the libraries to your project, you'll need to do `<ivy:retrieve/>` and then put that directory into your classpath:

Does this help you?

By the way, you might want to take a look at my Ivy setup project on [Github](http://github.com/qazwart/ivy.dir). If you have a lot of people sharing your
project, it makes it easy to include Ivy. Even if you simply create a `ivy.dir`
sub directory and not make it an included subproject. This way, no one has to 
install Ivy because it's already installed in your project.

Comment: I've added the [build.xml from the Android SDK](https://github.com/sschuberth/IvyAndroidExample/blob/master/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml) for reference. Note that I was in fact already calling `ivy:retrieve`, although the corresponding target in my build.xml was called `resolve`. I've renamed it to `retrieve` to match Ivy's terminology. Also, Ant on Android is configured to automatically add all libraries from `libs` to the classpath. So there should be nothing to do expect telling Ivy to retrieve the files to `libs` (instead of the default `lib`), which I did.